# Hair simulation freaking out

Tags: animation, modifiers, particles

I have been working on a Polar Bear for a school for a while now and I have a full rigify rig and shape keys for facial expressions but whenever i go to simulate the hair it spazzes out and bake a ball of hair that is useless. I need help Quick!

[image]

Comment: I expect your issue comes from your particle children settings. Maybe a high brownian under physics. Can you add a screenshot of those. or share your blend file [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: Here is the Link for the file.  I had to put it on google drive because the file was too large https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2P6Uof8h1lAVmJEM1h0NEU2cE0/view

Comment: Looks like you managed to sort it out the messy part, for some reason the solidify modifier is causing the patchiness that you have.

Comment: I turned off brownian, children and removed the solidify modifier and the hair does not move it just stretches everywhere.  I simulated it with just the solidify modifier removed and the haid freaked out.

Comment: If I open your file, enable the hair particles and goto frame 62 I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Q37.png) if I delete the solidify modifier I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oXEn2.png)

Comment: If you only delete the solidify modifier, on frame 7 the hair is still messed up for me when i simulate the hair.

Comment: It is definitely hair dynamics, jumping ahead to a frame looks fine but playing through frame by frame goes mad. I think you should [report it as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/). For now try with hair dynamics off and see if the result is ok.